# Strings read with scanf not stored properly

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, scanf

I am trying to read a few strings in the same `scanf()` but they seem to not be stored where I'd like them to.

My function:

```
typedef struct per {
  char *firstname, *lastname, *gender, *phone, *address;
  struct per *next, *previous;
} person_t;

person_t head;
person_t tail;

 void initialize(person_t *person) {
        person->firstname = malloc(20);
        person->lastname = malloc(20);
        person->gender = malloc(1);
        person->phone = malloc(15);
        person->lastname = malloc(50);
    }
void insert() {
  person_t *person = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
  person->next = &tail;
  person->previous = tail.previous;
  tail.previous = person;
  (person->previous)->next = person;

  initialize(person);

  scanf("%s %s %s %s %s", person->firstname, person->lastname,
    person->gender, person->phone, person->address); //END WITH ctrl-C

  printf("%s", person->firstname);
}
```

When I try to print the values in `person->firstname`, for example, all I get is garbage. I did allocate memory to each of those pointers.

I've read some things about `scanf` and it seems that it's not that great and all but I have to use it in this case. I don't understand the problems that come with it, however - something about buffers? Everything I read about it seems a little confusing.

Do you think the problem is related to the fact that it's reading the values into a `struct`? I'm saying this because it's the first time I've try to use that and, well, it's not working.

Comment: `person_t.firstname` is a *pointer*, but you haven't pointed it at any allocated memory.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart he specifically said he allocated memory for each of the pointers. I'm guessing that's what `initialize()` does.

Comment: You better to use `strsep()` and manually do the parsing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, that is correct

Comment: You'd better show us that `initialize()` function.

Comment: Reporting the return value of `scanf()` would be a good step.  `int cnt = scanf(...   printf("%d\n",cnt):`  Post input given, and output seen with `printf("%s", person->firstname);` to add clarity to this post.

Comment: The problem with scanf (at least in how you're using it) -- if you allocate 20 bytes for the buffer, and someone types in a 100 byte string, then the program will happily overwrite the 80 bytes following where the buffer was allocated (causing all kinds of memory problems).   You can use `%20s` to limit the number of characters stored...

Comment: No, it is not (directly) related to the fact that the pointers passed to `scanf()` are stored in structure members.

Comment: Why do you have to use `scanf` instead of `fgets`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Just did that.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @Dale My teacher asked us to...

Comment: Note that your `initialize()` function assigns two different values to the `lastname` member, and fails to intialize the `address` member.  This leads to undefined behavior when you try to scan input into the space pointed to by the uninitialized `address` pointer.

Comment: if this is homework, then I would suggest reading more about scanf to understand it.  I will be better for you in the long run to really understand it.

Comment: Having fixed that issue in `initialize()`, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: What is the input used?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I stared at the code for an hour and didn't notice that - thank you! Fixed that and now it's working :)

Comment: `person->gender = malloc(1);` is too small for a string read via `scanf()` and  `"%s"`.

Comment: @John [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788271/strings-read-with-scanf-not-stored-properly#comment76557796_44788271) mis-leads - off-by-one.  " if you allocate 20 bytes for the buffer," --> "You can use `"%19s"` to limit the number of characters "

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful/

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the "%s" input conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field to avoid a buffer overrun.  Such overrun is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: please post an actual/typical input

Comment: *but they seem to not be stored where I'd like them to.*   Show us the incorrect results AND what was actually entered.

Comment: @user3629249 I don't think there would be anything useful in doing that; the problem - in the initialize() function - was already solved by replacing person->lastname = malloc(50); with person->address = malloc(50);